# How remove the first line of the file when we are using getmerge in hadoop?

Tags: linux, shell, hadoop, merge, cloudera

I have three files in my HDFS location i.e.

`/user/cloudera/test/t1.csv && t2.csv t3.csv` each file size is 22Mb files.

So I am planing to merge the 3 files into one file.(i.e `t1t2t3.csv`).

So I used getmerge command.

hadoop fs -getmerge -nl /user/cloudera/test/t* t1t2t3.csv

Its merging properly but my csv files have some header like below

```
t1.csv                 t2.csv             t3.csv

name,branch           name,branch          name,branch
user1,cse             user2,ece            user2,ece
```

When i am merging using `hadoop fs -getmerge -nl /user/cloudera/test/t* t1t2t3.csv`

The header got repeated 3 times like below.

```
t1t2t3.csv
name,branch
user1,cse
name,branch
user2,ece
name,branch
user2,ece
```

I try to use "sed '1d'" i am able to delete header and  i can merge using below command.

```
cat t1.csv t2.csv t3.csv > t1t2t3.csv.
```

But I want to use only getmerge(hadoop file system commands ) .

Instead of downloading locally and removing header and merging using above commands.

please let me how can i achieve this ?